# iPhone+FBConnect - How to post video on Facebook

Tags: iphone, url, video, fbconnect

Is it possible to post video on facebook from my server? I have a server that hosts the video files. Can I send files from my server on the wall of the user?
May be FBConnect has the functionality send video with URL.

**For example:**

```
FBRequest* fbRequest = [fb getRequestWithGraphPath:@"me/home" andDelegate:nil];
TTURLRequest* request = [TTURLRequest requestWithURL: [fbRequest getConnectURL]
                        delegate: self];
...
[request send];
```

**Is it right?** Thanks all for reply!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could post the video on facebook,

Check the following very helpful SO post for uploading video on facebook

[iPhone Facebook Video Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355846/iphone-facebook-video-upload)

[Trying to upload video to facebook using FBConnect for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104660/trying-to-upload-video-to-facebook-using-fbconnect-for-iphone)